# less command in unix pipe

Tags: unix, pipe

I was hoping to pipe stdout to less to stdout to command to to less.
Like so:
`auval -a | less | grep App | less`

I was using this for debugging/learning purposes and would find it valuable. I hear less was not made to do this. Is there a tool for this in place, for use today?

Comment: The first `less` is pointless. If `less` is outputting to pipe instead of a terminal, it just passes everything through unchanged. Other than that, it's fine; I use `less` (or `more`) after `grep` and `awk` and `sed` and others all the time. ... That said, this question belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: Hi @honkyblood, could you please select an answer and mark it accepted to put closure to your question? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to debug, you could do this:

```
auval -a > output1.txt && grep App output1.txt | less
```

That way if you aren't getting what you want from grep, you could check output1.txt file in another shell or do `tail -f output1.txt` before running your command.

I agree with Sebastien that you don't really need less after auval -a. His proposal is the one I'd stand by also.

Answer (score 1):

```
auval -a | grep App | less
```

I fail to understand why you pipe to less before grep

Comment: Instead of less, a good word for the command I am looking for is `pause`. It would pause execution until manually resumed. `auval -a | grep App | less | pause | grep pp | less`  and execution would freeze at pause.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand a great deal about how the unix shell works. pause is a command similar to kill and does not work in the suggested pipe flow from your comment above. Maybe you should grab a book on unix system programming or bash scripting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tee` that *forks* its output to a given file **and** to the standard output, using your current terminal as the output file will give you the desired result:

```
auval -a | tee /dev/tty | grep App | less
```